# Docker: Connection refused for exposed port on localhost

Tags: docker

I have a Docker image that I processes an image with and get the resulting image using curl.  I exposed the port in my Dockerfile

```
FROM debian:latest

RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y git python3-pip python3-dev python3-tk vim procps curl

#Face classificarion dependencies & web application
RUN pip3 install numpy scipy scikit-learn pillow tensorflow pandas h5py opencv-python==3.2.0.8 keras statistics pyyaml pyparsing cycler matplotlib Flask

ADD . /ekholabs/face-classifier

WORKDIR ekholabs/face-classifier

ENV PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:src
ENV FACE_CLASSIFIER_PORT=8084
EXPOSE $FACE_CLASSIFIER_PORT

ENTRYPOINT ["python3"]
CMD ["src/web/faces.py"]
```

Once I build the image:

```
sudo docker build . --tag fc
```

I run my image using

```
sudo docker run -d -p 8084:8084 --name=face-classification fc
```

Once I do that I first try to curl for the output:

```
sudo curl -v -F image=@smile.png http://localhost:8084/classifyImage > output.txt
```

And get a connection refused error:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8084 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to localhost port 8084: Connection refused
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8084: Connection refused
```

At this point I wasn't sure if the connection is incorrect so I try a general curl to local host:

```
sudo curl http://localhost:8084/
```

And get the following error:

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8084: Connection refused
```

At this point I check to see if the docker port is exposed.  From this output it looks like it is not exposed since nothing is listed in Ports.

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-6-79:~/face_classification$ sudo docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                     PORTS               NAMES
2e343778c8fc        fc                  "python3 src/web/fac…"   8 minutes ago       Exited (1) 8 minutes ago                       face-classification
```

How do I go about properly making a connection?

Comment: The fact it says "exited" is not a good sign.

Comment: STATUS exited, is the answer the container died  you will need to check the logs using docker logs  to know why the process got killed

Answer (score 0):

Your container have status EXITED (You need to check your logs docker logs container_name ) or maybe you use ENTRYPOINT and CMD in the wrong way try :

> CMD [ "python3", "src/web/faces.py" ]

Hope it helps.